# Plotly graphs on huge dataset inside R Markdown

Tags: r, optimization, r-markdown, plotly

I have over 2 milion rows dataset and 15 variables. After I create plotly boxplot and histogram for all of 15 variables and generate html out of R Markdown I get 1GB file which is useless. Browser is not able to open it.

Is there any row/variable limit to work with R Markdown?
Is there any way to optimize plotly graphs?

On the 10.000 sample works fine.

Comment: The issue here is that the box trace of plotly needs the whole data set to be included in the HTML file. This is problem is being discussed on github and a possible work-around would suggest to create a 'custom trace':
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/242#issuecomment-181888414